# Not able to copy-paste in intellij 13

Tags: intellij-13

I am not able to paste text copied from outside intellij to intellij or other way around. Its used to work till yesterday and I am not able to figure out what changed (probably I updated it in my sleep) and its driving me crazy. I am using intellij 13 ultimate on on mac osx (10.9.4) . Any help is much appreciated here. Thanks.

Comment: not really a great solution but. I highlighted text on chrome, and then drug and dropped that text into intellij this worked for me. oddly enough after doing this i tried regular copy and paste and it begin working for me again.